# Swashbuckle.AspNetCore .NET 6.0 blank swagger site

Tags: .net-6.0, swagger-ui, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

I am trying to setup swagger for the product I'm developing and cannot wrap my head around it.

I started with the most basic config as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/getting-started-with-swashbuckle?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio). The swagger.json was generated correctly under https://localhost/MyWebAPI/swagger/v1/swagger.json, but when navigating to https://localhost/MyWebAPI/swagger/index.html I get a blank site. Did some digging and most of the answers were revolving around setting up SwaggerEndpoint, RoutePrefix or some uri templates but none of them worked for me so I finally did what should have done in the first place and checked code of the site itself.

It is there... The url's seems correct:

```
 var configObject = JSON.parse('{"urls":[{"url":"v1/swagger.json","name":"MyApp v1"}],"deepLinking":false,"persistAuthorization":false,"displayOperationId":false,"defaultModelsExpandDepth":1,"defaultModelExpandDepth":1,"defaultModelRendering":"example","displayRequestDuration":false,"docExpansion":"list","showExtensions":false,"showCommonExtensions":false,"supportedSubmitMethods":["get","put","post","delete","options","head","patch","trace"],"tryItOutEnabled":false}');
 var oauthConfigObject = JSON.parse('{"scopeSeparator":" ","scopes":[],"useBasicAuthenticationWithAccessCodeGrant":false,"usePkceWithAuthorizationCodeGrant":false}');

 // Workaround for https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/5945
 configObject.urls.forEach(function (item) {
      if (item.url.startsWith("http") || item.url.startsWith("/")) return;
      item.url = window.location.href.replace("index.html", item.url).split('#')[0];
 });
```

The issue is and I kid you not the line with interceptors [that is actually split into several lines and the browser wouldn't recognise it as a correct string.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fSnyM.png)
Obviously I tried to pass null as the entire section, but that just brakes everything two lines later. I am in shambles...

I tried with several versions of Swashbuckle (currently using 6.5.0, but tried with some previous ones starting from 6.1.5). Any ideas how to fix it as I guess this must be generally working but there's just something weird/wrong that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

Right... one of the most stupid things I've encountered lately. I started reading Swashbuckle source code and the only class that when serialised wouldn't get the JsonSerializerOptions as defined in Swashbuckle project is InterceptorFunctions, so it used mine... and mine would have WriteIndented set as true...